# Character replacement in batch fashion in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, character

I'm using windows 7 system.

I have about 1k text files in 50 different folders. I'd like to replace `;` in all files into `,`. What's the most efficient way to do so?

Suppose we have
`D\D1\f1.txt` `D\D1\f2.txt` `D\D2\t1.txt` `D\D2\t2.txt`, etc.

I'd like to: for each file of dir `D` (or sub-dir of `D`), replace `;` in this file by `,`, then rename or create a new file with name `original_name_Modified.txt` respectively.

I know that I can write a C or JAVA code to replace the character, can we do it in cmd script like shell script in Linux? And how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to use Dbenham's [repl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855&mobile=on)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This bat might help. But the problem is: 1. to fetch each file under each directory of the current director, 2. replace the content ';' of each file by ','. 3. output the changed file to orignal_name_Modified.txt or rename the changed file to o_name_modified.txt

Comment: Have a look at the output from `FORFILES /?`.